# SwiftUI TextField inside ListView goes blank after filtering list items

Tags: listview, textfield, swiftui

I'm working on an iOS app that displays a list of items that can be edited. For this, I'm using `List` and `TextField` for each of these items.

My application has some buttons that allow the user to filter the information that's currently displayed in this List. I've bumped into an issue that causes the `TextField` values to go blank after being filtered, and I can't for the life of me figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Here's a very basic reproduction:

```
import SwiftUI

let allItems = ["1. Foo", "1. Bar", "1. Baz", "2. Goo", "2. Gar", "2. Gaz"]

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var items = [String]()
    @State private var filterPrefix = "1"

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in
                    RowView(item: item)
                }
            }
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button("Toggle") {
                self.filterPrefix = (self.filterPrefix == "1" ? "2" : "1")
                self.items = allItems.filter { $0.starts(with: self.filterPrefix) }
            })
            .navigationBarTitle("Items", displayMode: .inline)
        }
        .onAppear {
            self.items = allItems.filter { $0.starts(with: self.filterPrefix) }
        }
    }
}

struct RowView: View {
    var item: String

    @State private var inputText = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("", text: $inputText)
        }
        .onAppear {
            print("Item: \(self.item)") // This prints the item successfully
            self.inputText = self.item
        }
    }
}
```

Upon hitting `Toggle` a couple of times, the `TextField` eventually ends up empty. However, the code in `onAppear` still prints the text value fine.

Here's a gif:

[image: Example]

---

Am I doing something wrong? Should I throw in the `TextField` only upon clicking? (seems like not a great idea, but I'm at a loss for why this isn't working)

I'm running on Xcode 11.2 beta 2 (11B44) but the same problem occurs on 11.1 and both iOS 13.1 and 13.2

---

EDIT: To further complicate things, I changed the row to include both text and textfield:

```
        HStack {
            Text(item)
            TextField("", text: $inputText)
        }
```

And now the `TextField` value doesn't go blank unless it's the last item in the list. Starting to smell like a bug to me

Comment: There is definitely a bug, I wrapped the `RowView` in a `NavigationLink` and it seems to stop them disappearing,

Comment: @Andrew interesting! Same results here, does seem like a bug then.. that's unfortunate

Comment: Since updating to Xcode 11.2 Lists in my app have become very buggy. Alignment issues, textfields disappearing, cannot delete rows (index out of range error)

Comment: Could you solve the problem? Try out the .id() modifier for the textfield, it helped me in some cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is now fixed in the latest Xcode beta (11.4)