# How to share data between class and view in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to build an 2048 game to learn SwiftUI but I'm stuck. I have three classes, Game, Board and Tiles. Game has a variable that contains an instance of Board and board has a variable that contains a matrix of Tiles.

In the same way, I have three views, ContentView.swift, BoardView.swift and TilesView.swift

In the view ContentView.swift I initialize Game like this :

```
@ObservedObject var game = Game()
...
Blocks(board: self.game.board)
```

Then in BoardView.swift :

```
@ObservedObject var board: Board
... Loop ...
TileView(value: self.board.board[y][x].value)
...
.gesture(
    DragGesture()
        .onChanged({ value in
             let direction = self.board.gestureToDirection(startLocation: value.startLocation, location: value.location)
             self.board.move(direction: direction)
        })
)
```

And in TileView.swift :

```
@State var value: Int = 0;
```

Game.swift :

```
class Game: ObservableObject {

    @Published var board = Board()

}
```

Board.swift :

```
class Board: ObservableObject {

    @Published var board: [[Tile]] = []
    /* Here is the logic of the game, when a gesture is triggered in ContentView.swift, I call a function to move the tiles */
}
```

Tiles.swift :

```
class Tile: ObservableObject {
    @Published var coords: Coords
    @Published var value: Int
}
```

My problem is that when I drag on the screen, the board doesn't change, and I have the feeling that the content of my board is not the same in my different files ...

How can I share data between view and classes ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is because the `@Published` changes are not published through the `board: [[Tile]]` array. I have run into similar issues, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60304281/3485670) for example.

One thing to try would be to give each `Tile` object a reference back to the `Board` that owns it, and manually trigger the board's `objectWillChange` when changes need publishing.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the following changes (scratchy):

1) Make a model, `Tile`, a value type

```
struct Tile {
    var coords: Coords
    var value: Int
}
```

2) Make a `TileView` present, as it sounds, a `Tile`, and give it a model as binding (@State is for internal usage, take a habit to give it `private`)

```
struct TileView: View {
   @Binding var model: Tile
   ...
```

3) make a bind between views

```
TileView(model: self.$board.board[y][x])
```